# Showing $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(2n-2)!\zeta (2n)}{\pi ^{2n}}(1-\frac{1}{2^{2n}})(1+\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}})=\frac{\log(2)}{4}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, riemann-zeta

How do I show that show $$\frac{0!\zeta (2)}{\pi ^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{2!\zeta (4)}{\pi ^4}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^4}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{2^3}\right)+\dots-\dots=\frac{\log(2)}{4}?$$

Comment: Where did you come across this?

Comment: It is very nice!!!

Comment: That $\log 2$ really has a thug life when it comes to $\zeta$.

Comment: Haha @VincenzoOliva The log 2 didn't choose the thug life; the thug life chose log 2 ...

Comment: This is beautiful. Quick, stick a few thougthts down before someone closes the question! :)

Comment: very nice... :)

Comment: for which category of people is the problem meant for?

Comment: I am very eager to see the proof

Comment: The factorial in de nominator makes me a little bit uneasy regarding the convergence of the sum... :/

Comment: The general term does not converge to zero, hence the series is not converging.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, did you check the numerical calculation?

Comment: where did you got this identity/equation

Comment: @ADG I got the identity by myself because the numerical calculations in my blood.

Comment: as if I'd believe this last comment.

Comment: @Ehegh: there is little to check, this series is not converging in the usual meaning, since $(2n-2)!$ grows too fast and makes the general term *not* infinitesimal. Maybe this question makes sense by considering Cesaro sums (just like we say that $\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n = \frac{1}{2}$ with a very special meaning), but as written it does not make sense.

Comment: @Jack that's a pity! Would be to nice if the stated result is true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer but kinda hint:
$${\rm B}_{2n}=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(2n)!\zeta(2n)}{2^{2n-1}\pi^{2n}}$$
So:
$${\rm S}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2^{2n}-1)(2^{2n-1}+1){\rm B}_{2n}}{2^{2n}(2n)(2n-1)}$$